# Ayuda tengo un problema con el map

Tags: c++, map

Buenas estoy teniendo un problema al insertar un objeto a un `map`. No se si es problema de la sintaxis o de mi codigo en general. Les paso una imagen si logran darse cuenta [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include "ManejadorProducto.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

ManejadorProducto* ManejadorProducto::instancia = NULL;

ManejadorProducto::ManejadorProducto(){}

ManejadorProducto* ManejadorProducto::getInstancia(){

    if(instancia==NULL)
        instancia=new ManejadorProducto();
    return instancia;
}

void ManejadorProducto::agregarProducto(Producto* p){
cout<<"id del producto creado:"<<p->getCodProducto() << endl;

cout<<"descripcion del producto creado:"<<p->getDescripcion() << endl;

cout<<"precio del producto creado:"<<p->getPrecio() << endl;

  producto.insert (it, std::pair<string,Producto*>(p->getCodProducto(),p));
//producto.insert(std::pair<string,Producto*>(p->getCodProducto(),p));
cout<<"hola";
}

ManejadorProducto::~ManejadorProducto(){
}
```

Comment: Puedes compartir tu archivo de encabezado `ManejadorProducto.h`?  En tu caso haces referencia al dato miembro `producto` pero parece que debería ser `ManejadorProducto::getInstancia()`.
Un pequeño tip:  para insertar en el mapa también puedes usarlo como si fuera un array/arreglo/matriz:
`producto[p->getCodProducto()] = p;`

El efecto es que si la llave/clave no existe, la crea, y si existe, la reemplaza con el valor dado.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar en vez de `producto.insert` `producto.emplace` ya que it que es el iterator no lo tienes declarado.

Otras cosas (tips para mejorar la calidad de tu código): no uses `using namespace std;` globalmente, usa `nullptr` en vez de `NULL` utiliza tabs en los scopes (dentro de las llavecitas) y cuando crees la implementacion de una clase no te recomiendo hacerla en el `main.cpp` sino en otro archivo por separado como `ManejadorProducto.cpp`

Comment: Buenas en realidad no estoy seguro cual es el problema yo en mi ManejadorProducto.h en la parte private tengo declarado mi map<string,Producto*> .Pero no se por que no me deja insertar ya e probado todo tipo de insertar en map y no me deja tambien probe cambiarlo por set o list y tampoco me deja.